# Tracking the last time a user accessed the site without excessive overhead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I would like to track the last time a user was active on our website.

One approach would be to write middleware that updates the database with every authenticated page request. However, I'm a little concerned about the overhead of such a technique.

I would prefer to just track the last time they logged in. And if they were kept logged in for 30 days, for example, it is accurate enough for our purposes to know they had logged in within that timeframe.

However, it appears that ASP.NET Core Identity might use a sliding window, where the 30-day counter is reset every time they access a page.

Is there any way to get a rough idea of the last time they were active on the site without having to update the database with every page request?

**NOTE:** With previous versions of ASP.NET, it appeared we had session events (start, etc.). Seems something like that would be ideal if it didn't require updating the database on every page request.

Comment: "Machine learning". You gather info over time; then chart trends. The "last time" is micro-managing ... if you have the time.

Comment: @GerrySchmitz: Last time is what our business needs are here. I don't really know what you're talking about. Machine learning is not a tool for determining the last time someone accessed the site.

Comment: "rough idea"; one person's rough is another person's smooth. You probably already have logging that logs requests to a log file. How much overhead could it be to add if the user is authenticated to that log? One bit.

Comment: You said you wanted a "25 cent solution"; "last time" implies "dates" which imples "detail". I don't know the "size of your shop". I doubt SO will ever care if I ever log in again ... they do care if as a whole, attendance drops off. I generalize; everyone else jumps to conclusions, prematurely.

Comment: You might check the answer in this thread?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296595/mvc-asp-net-identity-howto-log-to-db-when-user-logs-in

Comment: kind of surprising actually that's its not done automatically... seems like this should already be included in one of those identity tables.

Comment: @browsermator: Kind of seems like they did track this before .NET Core Identity.

Comment: not sure why this was closed... I don't see how it's "opinion based".  There is still a session here as the tokens are session cookies, no?  You would want to create your DB entry at the time those cookies are first set.

Comment: @browsermator: Me either. These days, it seems every question is downvoted or voted to close, no matter how good the question. It can be reopened if a few more people with sufficient reputation vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `LastActivityTime` with middleware to update the user's last activity time only if a certain amount of time has passed since the last recorded activity. This will reduce the database load. you could use in-memory cache to store the last activity time.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMemoryCache();
       services.AddControllersWithViews();
       .........
       .......
   }
```

Middleware:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
 using System;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ActivityTrackingMiddleware
   {
       private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

       public ActivityTrackingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
       {
           _next = next;
       }

       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IMemoryCache cache)
       {
           var user = context.User;
           if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               var userId = userManager.GetUserId(user);
               var cacheKey = $"LastActivityTime_{userId}";

               var lastActivity = cache.Get<DateTime>(cacheKey);
               if (lastActivity == default || DateTime.UtcNow - lastActivity > TimeSpan.FromHours(1)) 
               {
                   var appUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                   if (appUser != null)
                   {
                       appUser.LastActivityTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                       await userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);
                       cache.Set(cacheKey, appUser.LastActivityTime, TimeSpan.FromDays(1)); 
                   }
               }
           }

           await _next(context);
       }
   }
```

Do not forgot to register middleware in Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ActivityTrackingMiddleware>();
```

Comment: This is probably the right mix of function and optimization.